# Fedora 22 & 23 very slow

Tags: fedora, lag

**Background:**

I just recently installed Fedora 23 on a machine.  It was running very slowly, and initially only had 1GB of RAM.  So I installed 4 more GBs.  Still very slow.  I thought that perhaps it was a problem with Fedora 23 so I wiped everything and installed Fedora 22.  However it is still very slow.

**More Specifics:**

A terminal will usually open just fine, however as soon as I open Firefox (or Chrome) it will freeze for about ten minutes at a time.  It will also do some odd looking stuff while trying to render simple things like the browser. (See attached screenshot)  The most appropriate term for it would probably be "lag".

Rendering Issues:[image: Rendering issues:]

System Info from a memory test I ran earlier:  (In case that's Helpful) [image: System information from a memory test I ran earlier today:]

Inside my computer: (if that's helpful)[image: Inside Computer]

I'm stumped. What could be causing this?  And how do I fix it?

Comment: What graphics card have you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried an alternative desktop environment that would be less intense graphically? I think this is where your bottleneck lies. Check out the [Fedora spinoff that comes with LXDE](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/lxde/)? It's very lightweight in terms of cpu/gpu/memory usage and is a lot more graphically frugal than a gnome based DE. It should run well on the hardware you currently have. Go for the 32bit version, no need for 64bit on that PC.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, your bottleneck is going to be your graphics. And correct me if I'm wrong, that looks like an Optiplex... The system had 1GB of RAM to begin with, and that's an extremely low number, as far as desktop PC's are concerned. 4GB is kind of low too, but you should easily get away with it.

Your graphics are your bottleneck and you will continue to have issues unless you add a PCIe graphics card (it doesn't have to be super fancy).

Comment: Would this be anything more complicated than opening my computer and plugging it in?

Comment: Something like this? http://www.bestbuy.com/site/pny-geforce-gt-610-1gb-ddr3-pci-express-2-0-graphics-card-black/5594291.p?id=1218670822117&skuId=5594291